# error conversion to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, gcc, comparison

My errors:

> In file included from Main.cpp:18:
>   QuickSort.h: In member function `'void CQuickSort<T>::Partition(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >*, int, int, int) [with T = CMoviePointer]'`:
>   QuickSort.h:49:   instantiated from `'void CQuickSort<T>::Sort(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >*) [with T = CMoviePointer]'`
>   Main.cpp:70:   instantiated from here
>   QuickSort.h:31: error: conversion from `'std::vector<CMoviePointer, std::allocator<CMoviePointer> >'` to non-scalar type `'CMoviePointer'` requested
>   QuickSort.h:49:   instantiated from `'void CQuickSort<T>::Sort(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >*) [with T = CMoviePointer]'`
>   Main.cpp:70:   instantiated from here
>   QuickSort.h:35: error: no match for `'operator='` in `'*(p_vec + ((long unsigned int)(((long unsigned int)upper) * 24ul))) = temp'`
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/vector.tcc:156: note: candidates are: `std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = CMoviePointer, _Alloc = std::allocator<CMoviePointer>]`

And Here is my program.

```
#ifndef _QUICKSORT_H_
#define _QUICKSORT_H_

#include <vector>

template<class T>
class CQuickSort{
public:
    void Partition(std::vector<T> *p_vec, int upper, int lower, int size){
        if (size <2)
            return;

        int pivot_index = size/2;

        pivot_index += lower;

        while(lower < upper){ //do until start and end of list meet
            while(p_vec[lower] < p_vec[pivot_index]){
                lower--;
            }

            while(p_vec[pivot_index] < p_vec[upper]){
                upper--;
            }

            T temp = p_vec[lower];

            p_vec[lower] = p_vec[upper];

            p_vec[upper] = temp;  //swap upper and lower until lower is equal to or 
        }
    }

    void Sort(std::vector<T> *p_vec){
        int size = p_vec->size();

        if(size < 2)
            return;

        Partition(p_vec,0, size-1, size);
    }
};

#endif
```

I'm at my wits end. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or where the actual problem is. any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

`p_vec` is a pointer, and you are doing stuff like

```
p_vec[lower]
```

You could fix the problem like this:

```
(*p_vec)[lower] // or p_vec->operator[](lower)
```

or by passing the vector as a reference.

```
void Partition(std::vector<T>& p_vec, int upper, int lower, int size){ ... }
```

Comment: thank you! such a simple problem. I feel foolish.